# Is there any way to secure calls from JavaScript to a web service that will write to database with each call?

Tags: wcf

I need to create a web service to receive feedback from users from a "Was this webpage helpful to you? [Yes] [No]" JavaScript widget that we will put at the bottom of all of our website's webpages.  The goal is to have one web service accept requests from all of the websites and then the web service will insert data from each call into the database.

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to secure pure JavaScript calls to the web service.  I want to use C# ASP.NET for this, so my assumption is to use WCF to create the web service.  How can one secure these calls solely from JavaScript to ensure that they are legitimate?  Or is there a better architecture to consider?

Comment: WCF calls are still HTTP calls and you can use the same security mechanisms, eg basic authentication, digest authentication, certificates, Windows authentication, SSL encryption and more. What do you really mean by "secure calls"? Do you want to authenticate the users or encrypt and sign the messages? Why don't you simply use SSL?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi, by "secure calls" I mean I want to ensure that someone doesn't look at the JavaScript code in one of the pages and then use that JavaScript code to flood the web service with fraudulent calls, which would then be fraudulent inserts into the database.  My assumption is that if I just do a regular JSON, or other ajax call, from JavaScript then someone could take this JavaScript and use to for the attack on the web service.

Comment: All web sites face this. The solution is to use authentication and SSL to encrypt communications. You don't need to create a WCF web service, you can create a ASP.NET Web API REST service but the concepts are the same. Check [Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api), the articles in the [Security](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security) section and [Working with SSL](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api) if you want to encrypt communications